Getting lambda handler out of subfolder in serverless framework
I have this serverless.yml file which creates the lambda shown in the picture below.
service: backbone-framework

package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - "!*/**"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.10
  versionFunctions: false

  stage: dev
  region: ap-southeast-1

functions:

  handlerbot:
    name: prom-${opt:stage}-handlerbot
    description: Main bot handler
    handler: handlerbot.lambda_function.lambda_handler
    memorySize: 750
    runtime: python3.11
    timeout: 60
    package:
      include:
        - handlerbot/**
        - ../sls_helpers/**

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: false

After doing sls deploy, I notice that the lambda_function is inside a 'handlebot' directory. Is it possible to move it out to the main folder? i.e. prom-dev-handlerbot/ folder.

